# Is there a 'catch hold' rule when falling in 5e, similar to 4e?

Tags: dnd-5e, falling

Is there anything in 5e similar to the 'catch hold' in 4e when falling? We've been house ruling, but I can't find anything in the core books.

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain exactly what the "catch hold" rule from 4e actually is in your question (i.e tell us what you're trying replicate in 5e). That way answerers don't have to go searching through a bunch of 4e rules to try and figure out what you're actually asking of us and those who aren't familiar with 4e rules could potentially still help.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike 4e, 5e does not allow a saving throw to avoid falling by going prone. This was likely in order to simplify the 5e rules (plus, 'Pushes' occur less frequently in 5e).

That said, 5e seems to encourage DM's calling for rolls whenever it seems appropriate. So if a PC falls off a ledge and asks if they could grab something on the way down, a DM *might* allow it (if it seems appropriate) using the Ability Check rules (DMG p.237). Literal cliff-hangers are certainly fun.

However, usually there was already some sort of roll made for the fall in the first place (like an attack roll, or a Dex saving throw to avoid a pit trap).